# Is it possible to use dependencies without module-info.class in a Java 9 module

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I created two small projects *de.app1* and *de.app2*, where `App` from *de.app1* uses `Test` from *de.app2*.

```
├── de.app1
│   ├── de
│   │   └── app
│   │       └── App.java
│   └── module-info.java
└── de.app2
    └── de
        └── test
            └── Test.java
```

*module-info.java* in the first project just contains `module de.app1 {}`

I compiled the second project and created a jar file:

```
javac de/test/Test.java
jar cf app2.jar de/test/Test.class
```

and then tried to compile the first project like this:

```
javac -cp ../de.app2/app2.jar de/app/App.java module-info.java
```

which failed because `Test` could not be found. When I compile the project without *module-info.java*, everything is working as usual.

Is it somehow possible to use classes from a jar that is not a Java 9 module *within* a Java 9 module? Especially for projects that depend on 3rd-party projects (e.g. apache-commons,...), I think something like this would be required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. What you are looking for are [automatic modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules).

To create one you simply put a regular JAR into a folder that you mention on the *module path* (e.g. `guava-19.0.jar` in a folder `libs` - see [my example project](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jigsaw-advent-calendar/blob/04-automatic-modules/compileAndRun.sh#L50)). This tells the JVM to create a module from it. This module will get a name based on the file name (in this case `guava`), will read all other modules, and export all of its packages.

You can then require it with the name it was given (e.g. `require guava;` - see [here](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jigsaw-advent-calendar/blob/04-automatic-modules/src/org.codefx.demo.advent.factory.quote/module-info.java#L4)).

Comment: Nice, thanks! So in order for me to get this straight: When I'm working with modules, I should basically always use module path instead of classpath?

Comment: It's not that simple. The JVM will only load modules from the module path that are required by another module. Dependencies of automatic modules are not required by anyone (because they have no `module-info`), so they won't be loaded. They have to go on the class path, where they get bunched into the  [unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module).

Comment: If one automatic module depends upon another automatic module (i.e., both
are on the module path but only the first is required by an explicit
module) then you can cause the second automatic module to be loaded via
the [`--add-modules`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Root-modules)
option.  This option accepts various special tokens denoting useful
collections of modules.
[`ALL-MODULE-PATH`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#ALL-MODULE-PATH), in
particular, will load all observable modules found on the module path.

Comment: @MarkReinhold I know but I assumed that this was not the recommended way as it offers no benefit - or does it?

Comment: The key difference is that automatic modules are subject to sanity
checks, such as those for split and duplicate packages.  If you're
migrating an existing set of JAR files to modules then loading them
as automatic modules via `ALL-MODULE-PATH` can be a useful step
along the way.

Comment: There's the [java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Builder](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Builder.html) and other reflective classes that may allow you to create, manipulate and add modules.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. However, how does this work if I let Maven manage my dependencies and would try to avoid to manually place a JAR in my project?

Comment: Maven does this for you. All dependencies of a module go onto the module path, including plain JARs that will then get turned into automatic modules.