# Build module from jar with dependencies

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Is there any tool or technique to build valid [java-module](/questions/tagged/java-module) from old plain jar with its dependencies? It would solve split package problem in old libraries.

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269630/is-it-possible-to-use-dependencies-without-module-info-class-in-a-java-9-module), but automatic modules cannot help in this case.

Comment: Why can't automatic modules help here? Are you looking for automatic solution to split packages while you generate modules?

Comment: @nullpointer because jdk 9 will not compile module with such dependencies. Yes, it would be great to have some automatic tool that produces modules from project dependencies for you. Now I'm just can't use such libraries in my project, and I don't know any workaround for this

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.