# Issue with module-info.java and each external library

Tags: java

To explain the problem which I'm facing, I'll explain it with a new project.

Tools and setup:

- IntelliJ 2022.2.1
- JavaFX project
- Gradle based
- "Unirest" as external library

Created a new project and added the following dependency:

```
dependencies {

testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-java
implementation group: 'com.konghq', name: 'unirest-java', version: '3.14.5'}
```

After the Gradle's sync, I can see the library which has been added to this list:

[External libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIrgJ.png)

Now, in order to use the API, I need to update `module-info.java` as it follows:

```
module com.example.restfx {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires unirest.java;

opens com.example.restfx to javafx.fxml, unirest.java;
exports com.example.restfx;}
```

Now, I actually call whatever function of this library in my application.

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
    stage.setTitle("Hello!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    Unirest.get("...");



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

After launching the app this error appears.

> Task :HelloApplication.main() FAILED
> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module unirest.java not found, required by com.example.restfx
> Execution failed for task ':HelloApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I want to highlight the fact that this error will show up only if the project is created with JavaFX option. That means, a `module.info.java` file will be created, leading to this issue.

Actually if I create the same project, without using JavaFX, every external library works correctly.
Seems something related to that file, but I cannot figure it out what it is.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the unirest library, so I took a look at [its GitHub repo](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java). From looking at unirest's source code, it doesn't look like it defines a JPMS module. So you can use the unirest library only from the classpath and not from the modulepath. That `requires` statement you have in your `module-info.java` won't work.

Comment: Okay I got it. But issue now is, if I don't add that requirement, i'll not be able to import function in application side.

Comment: Perhaps [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269630/is-it-possible-to-use-dependencies-without-module-info-class-in-a-java-9-module) and its [associated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274483/16644458) might help. That question and answer doesn't involve Gradle specifically, but otherwise deals with how to depend upon a library that doesn't have a `module-info.java`.  You can do so with [automatic modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules). There should be a way to handle that in Gradle.

Comment: After my previous comment, I found an example on gradle.org with an example of [Building Java Modules with Legacy Libraries](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_with_transform.html) that might help you.